# How can "False positive" coverage in React Jest tests be avoided

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, jestjs

I have a quick React + Jest coverage question.

Consider the following:

```
function a() {
    console.log('hello from a');
    b();
}

function b() {
   console.log('hello from b');
}
```

If one explicitly tests function `a()`, coverage report will indicate false positive coverage for `b(). Is there a way to mark a Jest test to not give false coverage for b()?

I recall with PHPUnit you could use the *covers* annotation to mark that a test explicitly is only meant for a particular function or method.

For example you could do the following:

```
/**
 * @covers BankAccount::deposit
 * @uses Money
 */
public function testMoneyCanBeDepositedInAccount()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's unit testing, you should [mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html) `b` function while testing `a`, so `b` will not be called, e.g.

```
b = jest.fn();
a();
```